# A sun on the edge of our solar system takes an outlying crew to alternate versions of our solar system

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-travel

Years ago, maybe '80s-'90s, I read what I remember as a short story.

It was about an Earth crew stationed on a planet near the edge of our solar system. A sun appeared at the edge of our solar system, then disappeared and reappeared. The crew named the sun "Ronin." The members decided to hitch a ride with it the next time it appeared.

When they did, it took them to alternate versions of our solar system. One was silicon-based. There, they came in contact with a jellyfish-like race living in the upper atmosphere of Jupiter. A Jovian ship was coming to greet them until they realized that in this solar system, they were food to the jellyfish-like race. They had to escape, but the Ronin sun did not have a regular cycle. Of course, it appeared just in time.

This short story might have been in a paperback anthology. I remember paperback, but a lot of my sci-fi is in paperback.

Comment: They gave a Japanese-flavored name -- was the rest of the story/setting Japanese flavored as well?

Comment: @ZeissIkon, the rest of the story and setting was not Japanese-flavored, only the name of the sun. I suppose the crew named it that because ... well, it would be a master, not a masterless samurai. The rest of the story and setting was definitely "American" sci-fi.

Comment: Or perhaps because it was a dangerous wanderer...